# How to loop through multiple users and also through one user in FireStore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For my project I'm using Firestore and Node js. What I'm trying to do that in some case to read all collection of users and in other case read only one specific user with specific id.

Then I want to iterate through each user if it is all collection that go through all of them and if it is only one user again using loop iterate that one user.
The problem is that loop isn't working on one user.

This is how I read all users and one user.

```
const listUsers = await db.collection('users').where('age', '==', '36').get()

const user = await db.collection('users').doc(id).get()
```

So when I'm iterating through multiple users it is ok, but I want also to iterate through one user it says `user.map is not a function`.

```
   listUsers.docs.map((snapshot) => { //----working
            const user = snapshot.data()
})
user.docs.map((snapshot) => { // not working
            const user = snapshot.data()
})
```

So it it possible to solve this using loop in both cases?

Thank you

Comment: `user` will be returned as an object and not a list therefore you cannot iterate through an object. Even though your question is not clear enough what you want to do.

Comment: I want to have list of all users and also list of one user, so I can use loop in both cases

Comment: Convert the object to array. change const user = await db.collection('users').doc(id).get() to const user = [await db.collection('users').doc(id).get()]

Comment: oh stupid me..... thank you so much